# Solving for a list price when given purchase price and discount %

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

(Purchase Price - price paid by reseller)
(List Price - price sold for by reseller)
(Discount - percent discount for reseller)

For example, if an item has a list price of $100, and a purchase price of $75, the discount can be calculated by:

```
Discount = (List - Purchase)/List

Discount = (100 - 75)/100

Discount = .25 or 25%
```

I'm looking for the most simplified function to solve when either the List Price or Purchase Price is missing, here is what I have:

**1. Calculate List Price using Purchase Price and Discount**

```
List = -(Cost / (Discount - 1))
```

**2. Calculate Purchase Price using List Price and Discount**

```
Cost = List - (List * Discount)
```

Is there any shorter way to calculate this/simplify it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much simpler should that be? Both your formulas are already reasonably simple but a bit unusual. I'd say that a more standard way is

```
List = Cost / (1 - Discount)
```

and

```
Cost = List * (1 - Discount)
```

which clearly shows they are reverse to each other.